# Figures with caption inside tabularray (tblr) tables

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, captions, tabularray

I am trying to add captions for figures inside a table but am unable to do so. I have looked into this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843801/caption-for-figure-into-a-table) but having flexible `X` columns is not working as described.

The current output looks something like this.
[image]

The offending code.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=2in]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{tblr}{X[2,r] X[-1,r]}
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure A}
            &
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-b}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Error output:

```latex
You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. \end
Missing number, treated as zero. \end
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end
Missing \endgroup inserted. \end
Missing } inserted. \end
Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. \end
Extra \endgroup. \end
Too many }'s. \end
```

I have also tried with `caption` and `caption*` in place of `captionof`. Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put them in a \parbox:

```
\documentclass[margin=2in]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{tblr}{X[2,r] X[-1,r]}
            \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure A}}
            &
            \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-b}
        \end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works but the caption for the image is [out of alignment](https://upload.vaa.red/i/Hqpt9.png) for me. Can you confirm if that is the case for you as well? Could you also explain why `\parbox` does in this context?

Comment: Add \centering inside the \parbox.  The caption is (almost) always centered. similar to `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}`.

Comment: I understand. `\centering` centers the image. However, I wanted the caption to be under the image as I need `l` and `r` of the cells to function. Using `\centering` with `l` or `r` causes latex to ignore the cell alignment. Is there a way around the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add two libraries: `counter` (for correct caption numbering), `varwidth` (for eliminate your error) and  `tblr` option  `measure = vbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}              % version 2021P
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}    % <===

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c, wd=2in]  Q[c, wd=2in]},
             measure = vbox}         % <===
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure A}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Note, for above solution you need to use `tabularray` package version 2021P, which support/contain libraries `counter` and `varwidth` and should include `tblr` option `measure = vbox` . Older versions (before 2021N) doesn't support/ enables all aforementioned.

If you have older version of package (it is still in fast development) I recommend you to upgrade it. Beside mentioned recent version has some bug fixes too and also improved documentation.

Instead of `Q[c, wd=1in]` (width is taken from width of your images), you can use `X[c]` or `X[h]`. In this case compilation will throw warnings.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I directly tried running the code in the answer instead of augmenting it to fit the MWE. I receive the following errors: `Package caption Error: vskip undefined. \caption@ProcessOptions*{caption}`; `Failed to reprocess entire contents`. Can you provide some insigts regarding the matter?

Comment: @Rashiq, which version of `tabularray` package you have installed? I tested suggested solution with version 2021P (recent one) and it works fine. Try to upgrade package.

Comment: @Zarko it is an error from the caption package. The option name is `skip` not `vskip`. Beside this I get warnings from varwidth with your code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. `skip` is corrected now. About warnings: They are just warning, result is correct and present. Hopefully the package author will see this answer and your comment and give some suggestion about them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, if I replace column type `X[h]` with `X[h, wd=2in]` or with `Q[h,wd=2in]`, warnings disappear. Apparently automatic calculation of columns width beside that gives correct result also throw warnings (that column width calculation has some problems). This can be considered as (not harmful) bug ;-)

Comment: I'm using 2021P. Using `skip` solved the problem. Also using `X[2, c] X[1, c]` instead of specifying the `wd` (which is not suitable) works as well.

Comment: @Rashiq, if answer solve your problems, you may consider to upvote it and even accept it :-).